# Parse.com Cloud Code: Chaining functions?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm sure this is a simple one, but I just can't get chained functions to work in Parse.com's Cloud Code. I know it's possible - so this may be an indictment of my javascript n00bness. ;>

Below is a simple test function-chain that shows how I think it should work - but it doesn't. On `response.error` events, I seem to get errors, but on success I get:

`{"code":141,"error":"success/error was not called"}`

Here are the test functions:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("initialFunction", function(request, response) {

  var player = request.params.player;

  Parse.Cloud.run("chainedFunction",{ player: player.id },{
    sucess: function(results) {

      response.success(results);

    },
    error: function(results, error) {
      response.error(errorMessageMaker("running chained function",error));
    }
  });

});

Parse.Cloud.define("chainedFunction", function(request, response) {

  var player = Parse.Object.extend("User");
  var findPlayer = new Parse.Query(player);
  findPlayer.get(request.params.player, {

    success: function(player) {
      var games = player.relation("games");
      games.query().find({

        success: function(games) {

          response.success(games);

        },
        error: function(players, error) {
          response.error(errorMessageMaker("finding games",error));
        }

      });
    },
    error: function(player,error) {
      response.error(errorMessageMaker("finding player",error));
    }

  });
});
```

.. and here is my initial call to the function, for reference (though I'm sure this is not the problem):

```
curl -X POST \
   -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: <id>" \
   -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: <id>" \
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   -d '{"player":"<id>"}' \
   https://api.parse.com/1/functions/initialFunction
```

Comment: similar type of chaining problem .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32768731

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You misspelled "success" in your first options object.

Comment: amazingly this same typo was in my actual application code (the error was probably introduced by copying/pasting to this test), so i think you've actually solved it for me.. doing some testing to make sure this solves it for me.. but wow. ;)

Comment: that was it.. feeling lame. thanks very much for catching my mistake. ;)

Comment: Don't feel lame.  These kinds of things happen to the best every now and then

Comment: Reporting experiencing the same typo, unbelievable :) After hour of debugging my code finally I decided to go stackoverflow.. to my disappointment, the accepted answer was about typo.. then I checked my code and INDEED in only ONE place I've got "sucess". English - should learn it before JS ;)