# In cloud code, call a Parse.Cloud.run function more than once in series

Tags: parse-platform, promise, parse-cloud-code

Say you have a **"define"** Parse.com cloud code function...

```
Parse.Cloud.define("exampleDefineFunction", function(request, response)
    {
    ...
    response.success("ok")
    ...
    response.error("doh")
    });
```

I want to make another cloud code function,

which calls that define function **a number of times in series**,

with one waiting for the next, much as in a [serial promise chain](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#promises-promises-in-series)

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

I think this should do the trick!

In this scenario we want to use `Parse.Promise.when()`

> Returns a new promise that is fulfilled when all of the input promises
>   are resolved. If any promise in the list fails, then the returned
>   promise will fail with the last error. If they all succeed, then the
>   returned promise will succeed, with the results being the results of
>   all the input promises

I've tried to make it fairly self-documenting but let me know if you have any questions. Hope this helps!

```
// The promise chain for bulk image collection
Parse.Cloud.define("fetchBulkImages", function(request, response) {

    // Array of URLs
    var urls = request.object.get("urls");

    // Array of promises for each call to fetchImage
    var promises = [];

    // Populate the promises array for each of the URLs
    _.each(urls, function(url) {
        promises.push(Parse.Cloud.run("fetchImage", {"url":url}));
    })

    // Fulfilled when all of the fetchImage promises are resolved
    Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function() {
        // arguments is a built-in javascript variable 
        // will be an array of fulfilled promises
        response.success(arguments);
    },
    function (error) {
        response.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    });

});

// Your scraping function to load each individual image
Parse.Cloud.define("fetchImage", function(request, response) {
    ...
    response.success("image successfully loaded")
    ...
    response.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
});
```

Comment: Hi Russell, although I have not actually tested this yet - you've got the only cohesive answer!  So you deservedly take the bonus, thanks for that..

Comment: These will run in parallel, not serial.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a [beforeSave cloud hook](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code-beforesave-triggers) to do the pre-save checking?

In terms of executing them one at a time, you could look into using a [serial promise chain](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#promises-promises-in-series) to queue up whatever you need. Each promise will have it's own pair of callbacks for handling if the promise was resolved or rejected.

Also, the current setup seems like it will rapidly cause you to hit your API request limit. Have you thought about performing a single query with the array of URLs to check as a constraint. With that one query, you will know which of the items in the array already exist.

Comment: So the idea is that you feed in an array of URLs and you want to have a cloud function which will extract/scrape data from each site, but only if it hasn't already been visited? Does the order in which the URLs are visited matter, or are you thinking of doing it serially as a means to rate limit the requests?

Comment: I've got to head out for now but in the meantime this looks like it may be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870492/parse-promise-when-with-many-promises. I'll check back later and good luck!

Comment: Hi Russell, quite right. To clarify for newly arriving readers, the problem is using **Parse.Cloud.define** functions, in some sort of chain -- how to call those repeatedly in cloud code.  I am able to use "normal" functions (returning a promise) in a promise chain, calling those repeatedly in cloud code.